# is a query portable if the where-clause-value exceeds the column length?

Tags: sql

If I have an `acct_id CHAR(3)` and a query like

```
select * from some_table where acct_id like '12%3%';
```

will most relational databases accept this query or will some fail because I'm comparing a value longer than the column?

In other words: **will this query be portable across typical databases (like MySql, DB2, and Oracle) if my where clause exceeds the column's limit?**

Also, Is the same true for an `=` comparison instead of `LIKE`?

I tried a query on DB2 (x86 and mainframe) and it didn't cause any errors, but I wasn't sure about other databases. I looked through the titles of several SO questions before submitting.

Comment: Why can't you just try it by yourself?

Comment: I'd have to create tables and data (plus install several databases). I figured someone would know off the top of their head.

Comment: Use http://sqlfiddle.com and try without installing all databases. I've already tested for SQLServer 2012 and works fine - query is executed but returns nothing.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek AWESOME! I've never used it before. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only value that can be found in your CHAR(3) column that will match is `'123'`, but the `%` operators support 0 or more repeats.  There's no cause for the test to be rejected.

In fact, you could even compare `WHERE acct_id = '1234'` and a sophisticated optimizer might realize that no value will equal that and treat the term as false.  There's no obvious reason why this should be rejected as 'invalid SQL'; it is just an opportunity for dramatic optimization.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [@MarcinJuraszek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1163867/marcinjuraszek) in the comments I now know about [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) and it worked in each DB I tried it with:

- MySQL 5.5.30
- Oracle 11g R2
- PostgreSQL 9.2.1
- SQLite
- MS SQL Server 2012
- MS SQL Server 2008

Plus I tried it on DB2 Express-C 9.7.5 and DB2 on z/OS (mainframe) 9.1 and it worked in both.